# Express app req.body is empty on form submit

Tags: node.js, forms, express

Why am I getting an empty `req.body` here? I have looked through the other answers and I am using body-parser as they say.

Form:

```
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input name="input" placeholder="Shorten a link here..."/>
    <button class="shorten-btn" type="submit">Shorten It!</button>
  </form>
```

Server:

```
...
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
...
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("req.body :>> ", req.body)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form submits a url-encoded body. You should use the `urlencoded` middleware to parse it:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```